# Botón Avanzar/Retroceder no funciona

Tags: java, android, botón, audio, mediaplayer

Estoy intentando desarrollar un reproductor musical con MediaPlayer de android.
No se porqué no me funciona los botones para avanzar y retroceder la reproducción. Lo intentado casi todo, pero no entiendo el porqué el método seekTo() no funciona en esos botones.
Cuando pulso el botón parar me pausa la reproducción y actualiza la posición a 0, con lo cuál cuando se vuelve a reproducir empieza desde el inicio, esto es correcto. Pero con el mismo código lo utilizo para avanzar, no funciona. Este es mi quebradero de cabeza.
Gracias

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botonReproducir"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.751" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botonParar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:icon="@android:drawable/picture_frame"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.786"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.751" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botonPausar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="220dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.751" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botonAvanzar10"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.751" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botonRetroceder10"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.271"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.751" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="245dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="252dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/botonAvanzar10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/aldehueladeljerte" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        private MediaPlayer reproductor;
        private Context contexto;
        private int posicion = 0;
        private Button botonReproducir;
        private Button botonParar;
        private Button botonPausar;
        private Button botonAvanzar10;
        private Button botonRetroceder10;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            contexto = this;
            // Asociamos con sus respectivos ButtonView
            botonReproducir = findViewById(R.id.botonReproducir);
            botonParar = findViewById(R.id.botonParar);
            botonPausar = findViewById(R.id.botonPausar);
            botonAvanzar10 = findViewById(R.id.botonAvanzar10);
            botonRetroceder10 = findViewById(R.id.botonRetroceder10);
        /*Llamamos al método setOnClickListener() de cada botón e implementamos el método OnClick() 
          que nos servirá para determinar la acción del botón clicado en cada momento de la 
           reproducción*/
            botonReproducir.setOnClickListener(this);
            botonParar.setOnClickListener(this);
            botonPausar.setOnClickListener(this);
            botonAvanzar10.setOnClickListener(this);
            botonRetroceder10.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    
        // Método que elimina el recurso del objeto MediaPlayer reproductor 
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (reproductor != null) {
                try {
                    reproductor.release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    
            }
        }
    
        public void reproducir() {
            if (reproductor == null) {
                //Creamos el objeto MediaPlayer y le pasamos el contexto y la dirección del archivo de audio.
                reproductor = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
                reproductor.start();
                reproductor.seekTo(posicion);
            } else if (!reproductor.isPlaying()) {//MediaPlayer está Paused.
                reproductor.start();
                reproductor.seekTo(posicion);
            } else if (reproductor.isPlaying()) {//MediaPlayer está Starting.
                reproductor.start();
            }
        }
    
        // Creación del menú de acceso al reproductor de video
        //Método de creación del menú.
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            //Creamos una instancia del objeto MenuInflater.
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            //Lo asociamos al menú view.
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }
    
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            /*Si seleccionamos el item accesoVideo,llamamos al método onDestroy() que elimina el recurso
            del objeto MediaPlayer reproductor que estamos utilizando*/
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.accesoVideo) {
                onDestroy();
                //Creamos el intent para enviar los contenidos.
                Intent actividadVideo = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
                //Iniciamos la Activity MainActivity2 pasando el intent actividadVideo como parámetro.
                startActivity(actividadVideo);
                return true;
            } else {
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Funcionamiento Botón Reproducir 
            if (v == botonReproducir) {
                try {
                    reproducir();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // Funcionamiento botón Parar
            if (v == botonParar) {
                if (reproductor.isPlaying()) {//MediaPlayer está Starting
                    reproductor.pause();
                    posicion = 0;
                }
                if (!reproductor.isPlaying()) {//MediaPlayer está en Paused.
                    reproductor.pause();
                    posicion = 0;
                }
            }
            // Funcionamiento del botón Pausar
            if (v == botonPausar) {
                if (reproductor.isPlaying()) {//MediaPlayer está Starting
                    posicion = reproductor.getCurrentPosition();
                    reproductor.pause();
                }
            }
            // Funcionamiento del botón Avanzar 10
            if (v == botonAvanzar10) {
                if (reproductor != null) {
                    if (!reproductor.isPlaying()) {//MediaPlayer está en Paused.
                        reproductor.start();
                        reproductor.seekTo(posicion + 10);
                    } else if (reproductor.isPlaying()) {//MediaPlayer está Starting
                        posicion = reproductor.getCurrentPosition() + 10;
                        reproductor.start();
                        reproductor.seekTo(posicion);
                    }
                } else if (reproductor == null) {//MediaPlayer está Idle.
                    reproducir();
                    posicion = 10;
                    reproductor.start();
                    reproductor.seekTo(posicion);
    
                }
            }
            //Funcionamiento del botón Retroceder 10
            if (v == botonRetroceder10) {
                if (v == botonAvanzar10) {
                    if (reproductor != null) {
                        if (!reproductor.isPlaying()) {//MediaPlayer está en Paused.
                            reproductor.start();
                            reproductor.seekTo(posicion + 10);
                        } else if (reproductor.isPlaying()) {//MediaPlayer está Starting
                            posicion = reproductor.getCurrentPosition() + 10;
                            reproductor.start();
                            reproductor.seekTo(posicion);
                        }
                    } else if (reproductor == null) {//MediaPlayer está Idle.
                        reproducir();
                        posicion = 10;
                        reproductor.start();
                        reproductor.seekTo(posicion);
    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de un MediaPlayer para cambiar la "cabeza lectora" a otra posiciòn cuando estas reproduciendo, es importante:

- Pausar: .pause()
- Mover a la posiciòn deseada: .seekTo(position)
- iniciar la reproducciòn nuevamente: .start()

Por ejemplo, para retroceder este es un mètodo de ejemplo:

```
 @Override
  public void onRewind() {
       super.onRewind();
  
   int duration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
   int currentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
   int rewindPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() - 25; //*Actual posiciòn menos 25.

   if(rewindPosition > 0) {
      mMediaPlayer.pause(); //*Pausa.
      mMediaPlayer.seekTo(rewindPosition); //*Mueve la cabeza lectora.
      mMediaPlayer.start(); //*Reproduce.
    }

  }
```

Revisa el còdigo de este ejemplo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Notification-with-MediaPlayer

Comment: Muchas gracias, por responder y por el enlace.

Comment: Muchas gracias, por responder y por el enlace. Pero ese fragmento de código ya lo usé anteriorente, de hecho en mi código lo tengo así, exceptuando que no tomo en cuenta si el avance supera a la duración del audio.  En la acción del Button avanzar10 lo puede observar. El caso es que no me funciona. Saludos.

Comment: Disculpa. Mi error era tan simple que no habia pasado los segundos a milisegundos, por lo tanto mi código avanzaba y retrocedía 10 milisegundos que objetivamente eran imperceptibles. Un error absurdo, pero que ya no se me olvida. Por lo tanto, tú respuesta era acertada. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias @jarrapiu si la respuesta ayuda a resolver la problematica planteada en la pregunta, recuerda marcar como solución, revisa [tour], saludos.

Comment: He marcado tu respuesta como válida, pero según parece al no tener aún 15 puntos en mi reputación, mi marcaje no se muestra.